# how to synchronize audio and image

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I implementing media player which is using media store content provider which is providing the audio files stored now i want to use the corresponding  picture of that song displayed when playing audio file i came across usage of  `getEmbeddedPicture()` .but i have been  confused how to use that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fetch the Album Art from the media database in android and display the same.